# Word to describe pushing a chair under a table

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or a short phrase to describe the action of pushing a chair under a table?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Defenestration is a word that describes the act of throwing something out of a window...seems rather specific, so why not this?

Comment: @lux that is quite different from _pushing a chair under a table_. Plus, the down-votes have a different meaning.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, it is quite different, hence the need for the word.

Answer (score 5):

It's referred to as *pushing in your chair*.

Comment: Wouldnt it be a Kinetic Seating Device Action?